# Как посмотреть текст созданного запроса в jQuery.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Всем доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь поработать с REST API сервиса по документации. Через curl запрос проходит и возвращается ответ. А в jQuery.ajax() возникает какая-то ошибка, которая перебрасывает меня в функцию error со статусом 0. Ниже код:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://udsgame.com/v1/partner/company",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-Api-Key", "Здесь пишу ключ");
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-Origin-Request-Id", "Здесь Request ID");
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-Timestamp", "Здесь временной штамп");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#info").append("<h1>" + data + "</h1>");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status) {
        $("#info").append("<h1 style='color: red;'>Ошибка!</h1><p>" + jqXHR.status + "</p>");
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    $("#info").append("<h1>Завершено!</h1><p>" + data + "</p>")
});
```

В чем может быть проблема? Или как посмотреть текст формируемого запроса?

Comment: `console.log(jqXHR);`

Comment: Спасибо! Но мне, к сожалению от этого понятней не стало. Пишет  в statusText: "TypeError: Cannot convert string to ByteString because the character at index 10 has value 1058 which is greater than 255."

Comment: Я, вообще-то, имел в виду что бы Вы добавили этот консольный вывод в вопрос. Насколько я могу судить, мы видим серверное сообщение об ошибке, что, конечно, очень мило со стороны серверного кода. А запрос в браузере посмотреть можно нажав F12 - в закладке Network.